# Modal is invisible but its pressable

Tags: react-native

I have this weird thing going on.I navigate between screens , but when i switch screens i press a button and a modal must shown.Which its not, but the modal is there ... invisible.

So when i press an ivisible button(which i remember where it is) then it navigate to the screen that i want .

Its very tricky i dont understand why this happening .

Edit : i put a console.log for the state of the modal and its true ,it seems to overlay with my home page .When i return from a navigation screen it seems that is not re-renders the state .Why?

```
 <Modal
          animationType="fade"
          transparent={true}
          visible={ModalBookVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalBookVisible(!ModalBookVisible);
        }}
        >
                   
        <View style = {styles.bookModal}>
          {/* Book title */}
          <Text style = {styles.bookShowTitleText}>{bookShow.title}</Text>

          {/* Book category */}
          <Text style = {styles.bookShowCategoryText}>Category : {bookShow.category}</Text>
                    
           {/* Check if the book is Bought ,so it can show it,also we send the book */}
           <Pressable style = {styles.pressableInsideModal} onPress = {() => { boughtChecker() }}>
             <Text style = {styles.textInsideModal}>Show Book Bought</Text>
           </Pressable>
           
          {/* Check if the book is Rented ,so it can show it,also we send the book */}
           <Pressable style = {styles.pressableInsideModal} onPress = {() => { rentChecker() }}>
             <Text style = {styles.textInsideModal}>Show Book Rented</Text>
           </Pressable>

          {/* Pressable to Buy the book */}
          <Pressable style = {styles.pressableInsideModal} onPress={ () => {navigation.navigate('Payment',{paramKey:bookShow})}}>
            <Text style = {styles.textInsideModal}>Buy</Text>
          </Pressable>

          {/* Pressable to Rent the book */}
          <Pressable style = {styles.pressableInsideModal} onPress={ () => {navigation.navigate('PaymentRent',{paramKey:bookShow})}}>
            <Text style = {styles.textInsideModal}>Rent</Text>
          </Pressable>

          {/* Pressable to close the modal */}
          <Pressable style = {styles.pressableInsideModal} onPress={ () => {setModalBookVisible(!ModalBookVisible)}}>
            <Text style = {styles.textInsideModal}>Close</Text>
          </Pressable>
          
           {/* Here we see the book description */}
          <ScrollView style = {styles.scrollViewForDescribeModal}>
            <Text style = {styles.bookShowDescribeText}>Describe : </Text>
            <Text style = {styles.describeText}>{bookShow.describe}</Text>
          </ScrollView>

          </View>

                
      </Modal>
```

Modal CSS

```
//Modal for Books
  bookModal:{
    alignItems:'center',
    height:Platform.OS ==='ios' ? '70%' : '80%',
    width:'80%',
    backgroundColor:'black',
    marginTop:Platform.OS ==='ios' ? '40%' : '19%',
    marginLeft:'10%',
    borderRadius:25,
    borderWidth:1,
    elevation:15,
    padding:'1%'
  },
  //Modal Texts
  bookShowTitleText:{
    textAlign:'center',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    color:'white',
    fontSize: 15
  },
  bookShowCategoryText:{
    textAlign:'center',
    color:'white',
    fontSize : 15
  },
  textInsideModal:{
    textAlign:'center',
    color:'white',
    fontSize : 14
  },
  bookShowDescribeText:{
    textAlign:'center',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize : 15
  },
  scrollViewForDescribeModal:{
    backgroundColor:'white',
    flexDirection:'column',
    padding:'5%',
    borderRadius:15,
  },
  describeText:{
    fontSize : 15
  },
  //Modal pressables
  pressableInsideModal:{
    borderWidth:6,
    borderRadius:11,
    elevation:5,
    backgroundColor:'grey',
    width:'45%',
    height:Platform.OS ==='ios' ? '7%' : '9%',
    paddingTop:'2%',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
```

Comment: would you like to include your style? Maybe it's your background color issue. Secondly check your device dark mode.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Its not from my background color because its working fine when i press the first time.I will edit it just in case.